# C++ - Segmentation Fault - Dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have been trying to implement a dynamic array in C++ and got some troubles with the pointer references.

With the following code, I got a segmentation fault.

If I use the array and the size as global variables, the application works. I know I could do it, but I would like to know why it is not working.
I think I am losing the pointer array pointer reference, but I don`t know how to mantain it inside the method.

I don't want to use STL containers like vector.

Thanks for your help.

```
void addElement(int newElement, unsigned int * array, int& size ){
    /* create a temp array in order to copy the contents from the current array
    * it is needed because we want to increase the size of the array */
    unsigned int* temp = new unsigned int[size + 1];

   // copy all the data from array to temp
   for (int x=0; x < size; x++){
       *(temp + x) = array[x];
   }

   // add the new element
   *(temp + size) = newElement;

   size++;

   // release the memory from the temp array
   delete [] array;

   // the temp array turn into the temp array, that contains all the elements
   array = temp;

}

int main(){

    unsigned int * array;
    int size;

    addElement(1, array, size);
    addElement(2, array, size);
    addElement(3, array, size);
    cout << array[1];
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: [OT]: you may be consistent between `*(temp + x)` and `array[x]` notation.

Comment: *"I don't want to use STL containers like vector."* So basically you are saying "I don't want to use a proven, efficient implementation provided to me, but would rather use my time to implement something that probably won't work as well or be as fast." The standard library is there for a reason. **Use it.**

Comment: Hi cdhowie, I am not using vector because this question is related with an exercise that I am working on and the vector is one of the restrictions. In future projects, I will certainly use vector. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array = temp;` doesn't do what you expect as you pass `unsigned int* array` and not `unsigned int*&array`

Replace the prototype by

```
void addElement(int newElement, unsigned int*& array, int& size )
```

In addition, you should initialize your variable:

```
unsigned int* array = nullptr;
int size = 0;
```

and delete your `array` in main:

```
delete [] array;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This piece of code unsigned "int*& array solved" the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You did initialize neither pointer array nor variable `size`. So the program has undefined behaviour

Also the function has to be declared either as

```
void addElement(int newElement, unsigned int * & array, int& size );
```

or

```
int * addElement(int newElement, unsigned int * array, int& size );
```

Otherwise the ponter defined in main will not be changed.

For example

```
int * addElement(int newElement, unsigned int * array, int& size ){
    /* create a temp array in order to copy the contents from the current array
    * it is needed because we want to increase the size of the array */
    unsigned int* temp = new unsigned int[size + 1];

   // copy all the data from array to temp
   for (int x=0; x < size; x++){
       *(temp + x) = array[x];
   }

   // add the new element
   *(temp + size) = newElement;

   size++;

   // release the memory from the temp array
   delete [] array;

   // the temp array turn into the temp array, that contains all the elements
   return temp;
}

int main(){

    unsigned int * array = NULL;
    int size = 0;

    array = addElement(1, array, size);
    array = addElement(2, array, size);
    array = addElement(3, array, size);
    cout << array[1];

    delete [] array;

    return 1;

}
```

Or

```
void addElement(int newElement, unsigned int * &array, int& size ){
    /* create a temp array in order to copy the contents from the current array
    * it is needed because we want to increase the size of the array */
    unsigned int* temp = new unsigned int[size + 1];

   // copy all the data from array to temp
   for (int x=0; x < size; x++){
       *(temp + x) = array[x];
   }

   // add the new element
   *(temp + size) = newElement;

   size++;

   // release the memory from the temp array
   delete [] array;

   // the temp array turn into the temp array, that contains all the elements
   array = temp;

}

int main(){

    unsigned int * array = NULL;
    int size = 0;

    addElement(1, array, size);
    addElement(2, array, size);
    addElement(3, array, size);
    cout << array[1];

    delete [] array;

    return 1;

}
```

Take into account that there are standard calgorithm `std::copy` and `std::copy_n` declared in header `<algorithm>` that can be use instead of the loop within the function. For example

```
std::copy_n( array, size, temp );
```

or

```
std::copy( array, array + size, temp );
```

Comment: You miss the final `delete [] array;` in main.

Comment: @Jarod42 It is not me who missed delete. It is the author of the question. I am not sure that the delete is required for this test program.

Comment: As you rewrite code to fix it, it is better to show all (non stylistic) fixes. That underlines more that it is easier to use `vector` instead :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, if you insist Ihave added delete.